# Why react loads images for many times? is it possible to save the first load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, api, react-redux

to watch the problem you can vivsit the test site http://u100525.test-handyhost.ru/products

**the problem appears if to click many times on category items, images of products start to bug becouse react loads image of one item over and over again, on every change of category - on every filter of products, so how to make one load and save somehow the loaded images?**

so if i click on categories my code is filtering products array and update statement - visibleProducts then im doing visibleProducts.map((product)=>{});

and i`m getting bug problem, because every time when react renders my  the component does request to the server for getting image by id and waits while the image will load, but if i click on an other category react(ProductItem) starts other request for new images then it is starting to bug they start blinking and changing ;c

im new in react and just stated to practice what i have to do guys?

is my code correct ?

here is my ProductItem component ->

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, memo, useCallback } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setModalShow, onQuickViewed, addedToCart } from "../../actions";

import Checked from "../checked";

import "./product-item.css";
import Spinner from "../spinner";

const ProductItem = ({
  product,
  wpApi,
  addedToCart,
  onQuickViewed,
  setModalShow,
}) => {
  const [prodImg, setProdImg] = useState("");
  const [animated, setAnimated] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [itemLoading, setItemLoading] = useState(true);

  const checkedFn = useCallback(() => {
    setChecked(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setChecked(false);
    }, 800);
  },[product]);

  const onModalOpen = useCallback((e, id) => {
    onQuickViewed(e, id);
    setModalShow(true);
  }, product);

  const addHandle = useCallback((e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addedToCart(id);
    checkedFn();
  },[product]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setItemLoading(false);
  }, [prodImg]);

  useEffect(() => {
    wpApi.getImageUrl(product.imageId).then((res) => {
      setProdImg(res);
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className="product foo">
      <div
        className='product__inner'}
      >
        {!itemLoading?         <div
          className="pro__thumb"
          style={{
            backgroundImage:prodImg
              ? `url(${prodImg})`
              : "assets/images/product/6.png",
          }}
        >
          <Link
            to={`/product-details/${product.id}`}
            style={{ display: `block`, width: `100%`, paddingBottom: `100%` }}
          >

          </Link>
        </div>: <Spinner/>}


        <div className="product__hover__info">
          <ul className="product__action">
            <li>
              <a
                onClick={(e) => {
                  onModalOpen(e, product.id);
                }}
                title="Quick View"
                className="quick-view modal-view detail-link"
                href="#"
              >
                <span ><i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                title="Add TO Cart"
                href="#"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  addHandle(e, product.id);
                }}
              >
                {checked ? (
                  <Checked />
                ) : (
                  <span className="ti-shopping-cart"></span>
                )}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="product__details">
        <h2>
          <Link to={`/product-details/${product.id}`}>{product.title}</Link>
        </h2>
        <ul className="product__price">
          <li className="old__price">${product.price}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ options, cart, total, showModal }) => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onQuickViewed,
  setModalShow,
  addedToCart,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(memo(ProductItem));
```

here is my parent component Products ->

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ProductItem from "../product-item";
import { withWpApiService } from "../hoc";
import { onQuickViewed, addedToCart, categoriesLoaded } from "../../actions";
import CategoryFilter from "../category-filter";
import Spinner from "../spinner";

import "./products.css";

const Products = ({
  maxProducts,
  WpApiService,
  categoriesLoaded,
  addedToCart,
  onQuickViewed,
  products,
  categories,
  loading,
}) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [activeCategory, setActiveCategory] = useState(0);
  const [visibleProducts, setVisibleProducts] = useState([]);

  const wpApi = new WpApiService();

  useEffect(() => {
    updateVisibleProducts(activeCategory, products);
  }, [products]);

  useEffect(() => {
    wpApi.getCategories().then((res) => {
      categoriesLoaded(res);
    });
  }, []);

  const getCatId = (cat) => {
    setActiveCategory(cat);
    updateVisibleProducts(cat, products);
    setActiveIndex(cat);
  };

  const updateVisibleProducts = (category, products) => {
    let updatedProducts = [];
    switch (category) {
      case 0:
        updatedProducts = products;

        setVisibleProducts(updatedProducts);

        break;
      default:
        updatedProducts = products.filter(
          (product) => product.categories.indexOf(category) >= 0
        );

        setVisibleProducts(updatedProducts);
    }
  };

  let currentLocation = window.location.href.split("/");

  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <section className="htc__product__area shop__page mb--60 mt--130 bg__white">
        <div className={currentLocation[3] == "" ? `container` : ""}>
          <div className="htc__product__container">
            <CategoryFilter
              activeIndex={activeIndex}
              categories={categories}
              getCatId={getCatId}
            />

            <div
              className="product__list another-product-style"
              style={{ height: "auto" }}
            >
              {visibleProducts
                .slice(0, maxProducts ? maxProducts : products.length)
                .map((prod, id) => {
                  return (
                    <ProductItem
                      wpApi={wpApi}
                      key={id}
                      onQuickViewed={onQuickViewed}
                      addedToCart={addedToCart}
                      product={prod}
                    />
                  );
                })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  } else {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ products, loading, activeCategory, categories }) => {
  return {
    products,
    activeCategory,
    categories,
    loading,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addedToCart,
  categoriesLoaded,
  onQuickViewed,
};

export default withWpApiService()(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products)
);
```

and if you need, here is my CategoryFilter component ->

```
import React from 'react'

const CategoryFilter = ({categories, getCatId, activeIndex}) => {
    return (
        <div className="row mb--60">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="filter__menu__container">
            <div className="product__menu">
              {categories.map((cat) => {
                return (
                  <button key={cat.id}
                   className={activeIndex === cat.id? 'is-checked' : null}
                    onClick={() => getCatId(cat.id)}
                    data-filter=".cat--4"
                  >
                    {cat.name}
                  </button>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default CategoryFilter
```